# MySQL Unable to cd to '/nonexistent'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

After a server restart, our MySQL server completely broke. When trying to start Mysql with `service mysql start` we get the following:

```
Unable to cd to '/nonexistent'
......
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.5-m15 did not start. Please check logs for more details.
```

When typing in just "mysql" we get:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've tried to do:

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/run/mysqld
```

But it didn't fix the problem. Our logs are empty as well.

What is going on?

We're about to undergo a server reformat but we really need to backup our databases first. If we can't fix this problem, how can we backup our databases (without the use of mysqldump)?

Comment: You're aware that 5.7 is a Development Release right?

Comment: I installed it normally, I didn't even know that.